# I keep getting Unable to resolve {URL}. Try checking the URL for validity

Tags: google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

For a few weeks now I have been getting Unable to resolve https://enatosdigital.com/. Try checking the URL for validity. When I try using page speed insights. Can anyone help me with the cause of the problem and a possible solution?

But at the same time the URL still loads up on browsers.

I tried changing the DNS server but it still hasn't worked

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it works intermittently. It works in the browser too, but definitely slow to do that first connection (maybe it was making a few attempts?)

When I used a tool like https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/enatosdigital.com to test it globally a lot of countries were failing to resolve that domain (though now all but two are).

I would suggest you contact your DNS provider. [It's always DNS](https://www.cscdbs.com/blog/why-dns-is-the-biggest-single-point-of-failure/)